# WooCommerce Add Fee and Coupon to Programmatically Created Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on a function that creates an order / subscription for a specified user. This part works perfectly but I am unable to add fees or coupons to the order. I have tried using add_fee() and add_discount() on the order object. The add_discount() function just breaks my function so I'm asuming this function cannot be used on the order object. And add_fee() just adds a fee called 'fee' with no value.

So how can I add fees and coupons to a programmatically created order?

Here's my function:

```
function give_user_subscription($companyId, $productId, $companyName) {
    // get the primary contact ID for the company
    $primaryUser = get_users( array(
        'fields' => array('ID'),
        'meta_query' =>
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'company_id',
                    'value'   => $companyId,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'primary_contact',
                    'value'   => 1,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            ),
    ) );

    $userId = $primaryUser[0]->ID;
    $user = get_user_by('ID', $userId);

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => $user->first_name,
        'last_name' => $user->last_name,
        'email' => $user->user_email,
        'phone' => get_user_meta($userId, 'mobile', true),
        'address_1' => get_user_meta($userId, 'address_line_1', true),
        'address_2' => get_user_meta($userId, 'address_line_2', true),
        'city' => get_user_meta($userId, 'town', true),
        'postcode' => get_user_meta($userId, 'postcode', true),
        'country' => get_user_meta($userId, 'country', true),
        'company' => $companyName
    );

    // order object
    $order = wc_create_order(array( 
        'customer_id'   => $userId
    ));

    $order->set_address($address, 'billing'); // Set customer billing adress

    $order->add_fee( 'Sign Up Fee', 1500 );
    $order->add_discount('NOFEE');
    
    $product = wc_get_product($productId);
    $order->add_product($product, 1); // Add an order line item
    
    // Set payment gateway
    $payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
    $order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways['bacs'] );
    
    $order->calculate_totals(); // Update order taxes and totals
    $order->update_status('completed', 'Manual approval ', true); // Set order status and save

    $subscription = wcs_create_subscription(array(
        'status' => 'pending',
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'customer_id' => $userId,
        'billing_period' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period($product),
        'billing_interval' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval($product),
    ));


    // if( is_wp_error( $subscription ) ){
    //     echo $subscription->get_error_message();
    //     // return false;
    // }

    $start_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // Add product to subscription
    $subscription->add_product($product, 1);

    $dates = array(
        'trial_end' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_trial_expiration_date( $product, $start_date ),
        'next_payment' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_first_renewal_payment_date( $product, $start_date ),
        'end' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_expiration_date( $product, $start_date ),
    );

    $subscription->update_dates($dates);
    $subscription->set_address($address, 'billing');
    $subscription->calculate_totals();

    // Update order status with custom note
    $note = ! empty( $note ) ? $note : __('Manually added order and subscription.');
    $order->update_status('completed', $note, true);

    // Update subscription status
    $subscription->update_status('active', $note, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        // Discount
        $coupon_code = 'NOFEE';
        $order->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );

        // Fee
        $fee_name    = 'Sign Up Fee';
        $fee_amount  = 1500;

        $item_fee = new WC_Order_Item_Fee();

        $item_fee->set_name( $fee_name );
        $item_fee->set_amount( $fee_amount );
        $item_fee->set_tax_class( '' );
        $item_fee->set_tax_status( 'taxable' ); // or 'none'
        $item_fee->set_total( $fee_amount );


        $country_code = $order->get_shipping_country();

        $calculate_tax_for = array(
            'country'    => $country_code,
            'state'      => '',
            'postcode'   => '',
            'city'       => ''
        );

        $item_fee->calculate_taxes( $calculate_tax_for );

        $order->add_item( $item_fee );
```

Try this code

Comment: The fee section works perfectly I managed to figure that part out. But the coupon section doesn't show any coupons in the order. I nearly got it working with WC_Order_Item_Coupon() but this only shows the coupon on the order and didn't actually apply the discount